# How to change form action of wp-login page with a function

Tags: functions, url-rewriting, actions, forms, wp-login-form

I'm manually creating my own Wordpress login form. The `action` parameter of all the forms points to `wp-login.php`. I want to change it for all of them to custom url (`/login`). Any idea how to that?

For example:

```
<form name="lostpasswordform" id="lostpasswordform"
action="http://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword" method="post">
```

So I want to change the form action into `mywebsite.com/login/?action=lostpassword` 
**Note, I need for both `Login`, `Register` and `Lost Password`.**

Kind regards.

Comment: I think you could to this with an Url rewrite rule, either in `htaccess` or using WP's  [rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API).

Comment: @Michael neither way, it's out of question. in WP, you ***almost*** never need to  (and shoulnd't) touch `htaccess`, unless no other way remains there.

Answer (score 0):

Follow standards instead of ugly solutions. Use WP filter (put inside functions.php):

```
add_filter( 'site_url', 'my_url_modifier', 10, 4 );

function my_url_modifier( $url, $path, $scheme, $blog_id)
{
    if($url=='http://mywebsite.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword')   
        return 'http://your_link..';
    else 
        return $url;
}
```

p.s. You should add other links there link example. Also, you can sanitise further parameters, like : `if ($path=='wp-login.php')....`